# jQuery Dialog Button positioning

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to position 2 Buttons in a jQuery Dialog.
In my default settings the buttons are initialised on top of each other.
I need them side by side.

Anyone with experience regarding this problem?

Here my init options:

```
var dialogOpts = {
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "OK": function () {
                if (window.currentNodeValue != null) {
                    //Not interesting
                } else {
                    //Not interesting
                }

            },
            "Abbrechen": function () {
                //Not interesting
            }
        },
        width: 500,
        height: 600,
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false
    };
```

Comment: It looks like a CSS problem instead of a JS one.. can you post the html code of the dialog box?

Answer (score 1):

There might be a few similar reasons for it, but what seems most likely is that your site's CSS sets default `display` style for `button` element to `block`. Try setting it manually to `inline` via Firebug. If that helps, simply add this at the end of your CSS file

```
.ui-dialog-buttonset button.ui-button {display:inline;}
```